# How to pass multiple interrelated columns to the function on groupby and agg?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
id  col1   col2
1   7      1.2
1   6      0.8
1   12     0.9
1   1      1.1
2   3      2.0
2   6      1.8
3   10     0.7
3   11     0.9
3   12     1.2
```

Here is the code to create this `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 
                   'col1': [7,6,12,1,3,6,10,11,12],
                   'col2': [1.2,0.8,0.9,1.1,2.0,1.8,0.7,0.9,1.2]})
```

I need to group by `id` and apply the function `myfunc` to each group. The problem is that `myfunc` requires several interrelated columns as an input. The final goal is to create a new column `new_col` for each `id`.

How can I do it?

This is my current code:

```
def myfunc(df, col1, col2):

    df1 = col1
    df2 = df[df[col2] < 1][[col1]]
    var1 = df1.iloc[0]
    var2 = df2.iloc[0][0]

    result = var2 - var1

    return result


df["new_col"] = df.groupby("id").agg(myfunc(...??))
```

Comment: [How to make a good and reproducible Pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Maybe are you looking for [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) (instead of `agg`) ?

Comment: @AlexandreB.: The function is supposed to take the first value of `col1` as `var1` and the first value of `col1` by the condition on `col2` as `var2`. Then I should calculate the difference between `var1` and `var2`. See the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In groupby-apply, `my_func()` is passed the entire group, with all columns. You can simply select the columns from that group:

```
def myfunc(g):
    var1 = g['col1'].iloc[0]
    var2 = g.loc[g['col2'] > 1, 'col1'].iloc[0]

    return var1 / var2

df['new_col'] = df.groupby("id").apply(myfunc)
```

Comment: Can I do something like this?: `df[['new_col1','new_col2']] = df.groupby("id").apply(myfunc1,myfunc2)`

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751127/returning-multiple-values-from-pandas-apply-on-a-dataframe), but please stay on topic here.